# How to use settings from integration testing project in the Startup class of api project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing

I'm trying to write integration tests for web api, I have two appsettings.json files one for api project and other for integration tests. I want to use the values(azure storage connection strings) from integration testing project in Startup class of web api.

I have tried creating CustomWebApplicatonFactory it didn't work since the Startup class of web api gets settings like shown below.

```
//Configure services method in Startup class
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      var settings = ConfigurationProvider.GetConfiguration();
      services.TryAddSingleton(settings);
      services.AddHttpClient();
      var azureTableStorageConnectionString = 
      settings["AzureMainStoreConnectionStringSecretName"];

     //Other Startup related code
}
```

I want to change the value of "azureTableStorageConnectionString" from my integration test project. Help and suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, instead of using the static function `ConfigurationProvider.GetConfiguration()` inject `IConfiguration` into your `Startup` class. The host that is usually defined in the `Program` class builds that for you so you can inject it.

Then instead of using `WebApplicationFactory<TStartup>` you can build a test-host yourself like this.

```
[Fact]
public async Task LoadWeatherForecastAsync()
{
    var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
        {
            builder.Sources.Clear();
            builder.SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
            // this is an appsettings file located in the test-project!
            builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Testing.json", false);
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();

    var host = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);

    var response = await host.CreateClient().GetAsync("weatherforecast");

    Assert.True(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
}
```

I've created a sample on [github](https://github.com/alsami/AspNetCore.WebApi.Testing). You can clone it and try it out.